# How to handle NestJS Dependency Injection when extending a class for a service?

Tags: mongoose, dependency-injection, subclass, extends, nestjs

I am trying to provide a different service based on a value from my `ConfigService`.

The problem I am running into is that the mongoose model that gets injected does not return any values when executing query methods such as `findOne()` (result is `null`) or `countDocuments()` (result is `0`).

My service classes are defined as follows:

```js
    export class BaseService {
      constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') public readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {}

      createService(option: string) {
        if (option === 'OTHER') {
          return new OtherService(this.catModel);
        } else if (option === 'ANOTHER') {
          return new AnotherService(this.catModel);
        } else {
          return new BaseService(this.catModel);
        }
      }

      async findOne(id: string): Promise<Cat> {
        return await this.catModel.findOne({_id: id});
      }

      async count(): Promise<number> {
        return await this.catModel.countDocuments();
      }

      testClass() {
        console.log('BASE SERVICE CLASS USED');
      }
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class OtherService extends BaseService {
      constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') public readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {
        super(catModel);
      }

       testClass() {
        console.log('OTHER SERVICE CLASS USED');
      }
    }

    @Injectable()
    export class AnotherService extends BaseService {
      constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') public readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {
        super(catModel);
      }
      testClass() {
        console.log('ANOTHER SERVICE CLASS USED');
      }
    }
```

This allows me to get the correct service from my provider (`testClass()` prints the expected string). My provider looks like this:

```js
    export const catProviders = [
      {
        provide: 'CatModelToken',
        useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('CAT', CatSchema),
        inject: ['DbConnectionToken'],
      },
      {
        provide: 'BaseService',
        useFactory: (ConfigService: ConfigService, connection: Connection) => {
          const options = ConfigService.get('SERVICE_TYPE');
          let model = connection.model('CAT', CatSchema);
          return new BaseService(model).createService(options);
      },
      inject: [ConfigService, 'CatModelToken', 'DbConnectionToken'],
      }
    ];
```

So my question is in two parts:

- Is there a better way to handle the creation of the correct class and
  to avoid having to create a `BaseService` instance for the sole
  purpose of calling `createService()`?
- What is the proper way to inject the mongoose model into the newly created service?

I also cannot use the `useClass` example from the documentation, since I need to be able to inject the `ConfigService`.

Answer (score 11):

You can solve this by using a factory approach, try this:

Interface to determine the "shape" of your services:

```typescript
export interface IDatabaseService {
    findOne(id: string): Promise<Cat>;
    count(): Promise<number>;
    testClass(): void;
}
```

The BaseService must implement that interface:

```typescript
export class BaseService implements IDatabaseService {

    constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') public readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {}

    async findOne(id: string): Promise<Cat> {
        return await this.catModel.findOne({_id: id});
    }

    async count(): Promise<number> {
        return await this.catModel.countDocuments();
    }

    testClass() {
        console.log('BASE SERVICE CLASS USED');
    }
}
```

The dynamic services are not injected so they do not use the `@Injectable()` decorator:

```typescript
export class OtherService extends BaseService {

    constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') public readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {
        super(catModel);
    }

    testClass() {
        console.log('OTHER SERVICE CLASS USED');
    }
}

export class AnotherService extends BaseService {

    constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') public readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {
        super(catModel);
    }

    testClass() {
        console.log('ANOTHER SERVICE CLASS USED');
    }
}
```

The factory class is the thing that gets injected:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class DatabaseServiceFactory {

    constructor(@InjectModel('Cat') private readonly catModel: Model<Cat>) {}

    createService(name: string) : IDatabaseService {
        switch(name) {
            case 'other': return new OtherService(this.catModel);
            case 'another': return new AnotherService(this.catModel);
            default: throw new Error(`No service has been implemented for the name "${name}"`);
        }
    }
}
```

```typescript
export const catProviders = [
    {
        provide: 'CatModelToken',
        useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model('CAT', CatSchema),
        inject: ['DbConnectionToken'],
    },
    {
        provide: 'BaseService',
        useFactory: (ConfigService: ConfigService, connection: Connection, dbFactory: DatabaseServiceFactory) => {

            const options = ConfigService.get('SERVICE_TYPE');
            let model = connection.model('CAT', CatSchema);
            
            //return new BaseService(model).createService(options);
            return dbFactory.createService(options);
        },
        inject: [
            ConfigService,
            'CatModelToken',
            'DbConnectionToken',
            DatabaseServiceFactory
        ],
    }
];
```